# Ruby как выполнить слияние массива в хэш

Tags: массивы, ruby

Добрый день.
У меня есть массив

```
[[6, 17], [3, 18], [6, 18], [3, 19], [6, 19],....]
```

как с помощью Ruby, его преобразовать в

```
{3 => [18,19], 6=>[17,18,19],......}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться итератором `inject`, передав ему хэш со значением ключа по умолчанию равным новому массиву (в блоке ниже хэш обозначается `m`)

```
arr = [[6, 17], [3, 18], [6, 18], [3, 19], [6, 19]]
res = arr.inject(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |m, a|
  m[a.first] << a.last
  m
end
p res # {6=>[17, 18, 19], 3=>[18, 19]}
```

Или, еще лучше, воспользоваться итератором `each_with_object`, который позволяет уложиться в одну строку в блоке

```
arr = [[6, 17], [3, 18], [6, 18], [3, 19], [6, 19]]
res = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |a, m| m[a.first] << a.last }
p res # {6=>[17, 18, 19], 3=>[18, 19]}
```

Здесь в качестве объекта так же выступает хэш, элементам которого по умолчанию присваивается массив `Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }`.